# What would be the best approach to show a message to user when a process is done in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

A user uploads a file and in background I would import some data from that file into DB, after the process is done or failed I would like to show a message to user.

What would be the best approach to show the message even user goes to another pages?
Should I add an interval in my root component to check the status of that file? or is there any other solution?

Comment: you can use any library which shows messages or just create a component for this with some internal logic, use this component in the root, and when you want to show the message just dispatch an action, I will try to answer your question in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const Toast = () => {
  const { message } = useSelector(state => state.toast)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (message) {
      setShow(true)
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
         setShow(false)
         dispatch(showMessage(''))
      }, 5000)
    }
    return () => {
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        setShow(false)
      }
    }
  }, [message])

  return show ? <div>{{ message }}</div> : null;
}
```

```
export const App = () => {
  return <div>
    <InternalApp />
    <Toast />
  </div>
}
```

```
export const InternalApp = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(showMessage('Clicked!'))
  }
  return <div onClick={handleClick}>data</div>
}
```

showMessage is an action which you import from created store

Comment: You may need to change the logic inside Toast for your needs